# How to get total sum of a single column value in ng bind..?

Tags: html, angularjs-scope

HTML CODE:

HERE IS MY HTML CODE WHERE I BINDED SUM OF TOTAL OF EACH COLUMN THROUGH NG BIND....

```
            <tr >
                <td> Totals </td>                    
                <td>  {{total ||'0'}}</td>                    
                <td>{{sum(user.creditTotal )}}</td>
                <td>{{sum(user.cardTotal)}}</td>
                <td>{{sum(user.saleAmount)}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Js:

I HAVE DECLARED SCOPE VARIABLES TO GET SUM OF TOTAL.COULD ANYONE HELP ME WHAT I DID WRONG IN IT.
AND (Data) IS WHERE I AM FETCHING  FROM API...

```
$scope.total = function() {
    $scope.cashTotal =0;
        $scope.creditTotal =0;
        $scope.cardTotal =0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(user) {
         $scope.cashTotal = sum(user.cashAmount);
         $scope.creditTotal = sum(user.creditAmount);
            $scope.cardTotal =sum(user.cardAmount);
       })

    return cashTotal,creditTotal,cardTotal;
    }
```

Comment: can you show an example of $scope.data

Comment: maybe this will work, https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1414/, i triggered the total function and also returned the correct value from the forEach function and presented it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do the trick. i triggered the total function and also returned the correct value from the forEach function and presented it in the view.

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1415/

html:

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr>
       <td> Totals </td>                    
       <td>{{total}}</td>                    
       <td>{{cashTotal }}</td>
       <td>{{creditTotal}}</td>
       <td>{{cardTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

javascript/angularjs

```
angular.module('myModule', [''])

.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.cashTotal = 0;
   $scope.creditTotal = 0;
   $scope.cardTotal = 0;

   $scope.total = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(user) {
         $scope.cashTotal = sum(user.cashAmount);
         $scope.creditTotal = sum(user.creditAmount);
         $scope.cardTotal =sum(user.cardAmount);
       })

    return  $scope.cashTotal, $scope.creditTotal, $scope.cardTotal;
    }

     $scope.total();


});
```